# Change Encoding of tibble columns in tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, encoding, tidyverse

I have data from a MySQL databases which returns latin1 encoded with hex in the following format:

```
> data
# A tibble: 52 × 4
      id code   swe_name         eng_name          
   <int> <chr>  <chr>            <chr>             
 1     0 ""     ""               ""                
 2     1 "M"    "muskel"         "muscle"          
 3     2 "L"    "lever"          "liver"           
 4     3 "N"    "njure"          "kidney"          
 5     4 "Fj"   "fj\xe4der"      "feather"         
 6     5 "Hj"   "hj\xe4rna"      "brain"           
 7     6 "\xd6" "\xf6vrigt"      "other"           
 8     7 "Ind"  "hela individen" "whole individual"
 9     8 "F"    "fett/talg"      "fat"             
10     9 "DF"   "sp\xe4ck"       "lard"            
# ℹ 42 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

I need to set the Encoding of the  columns to "latin1".
I can do it 'manually' with:

```
for (c in colnames(data)[vapply(data, is.character, TRUE)]) {
    Encoding(data[, c, drop = TRUE]) <- "latin1" 
}
```

This however is hard to read and feels clunky. I thought of using dplyr, where the columns can be selected nicely using

```
data |> select_if(is.character)
```

or

```
data |> mutate(across(where(is.character), ...))
```

and I've think it might be possible to use `mutate` and `across`, but the `Encoding(x) <- "latin1"` isn't really a function that can be applied in place, and `function(x) { Encoding(x) <- "latin1" }` doesn't work.

If possible (or preferable) how can this be done using dplyr and tidyverse?
Since the column-selection is so convenient.

Comment: How are you reading in the data?  Better off to ensure it's read in with the correct encoding than try to fix it post.

Comment: I'm reading the data using RMariaDB to connect to a MySQL server version 5.0.77. I tried the `encoding="latin1"` option in `dbConnect`, but it didn't seem to affect anything.

When reading the data from a database dump I use for local testing (mariadb 11.0.2) I don't have any problems with encoding, only on the older database used in prod.

From the database connection I use dbplyr with `tbl` and then `collect`. So I thought I could add a function to set the correct encoding directly after the `collect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richie is right, it's better to read in the data correctly rather than cleaning after the fact. With that said, if you are forced to clean, here's a couple of ways of doing it:

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, across(where(is.character), ~iconv(., "latin1", "UTF-8")))
mutate(df, across(where(is.character), ~stringi::stri_encode(.x, "latin1", "UTF-8")))
```